What circuit breaker compatible with panel
My electric panel model is square d sc816d200c. I’m looking for the 50 amps circuit breaker using for installing EV charging.
I took a picture of a model and then asked Lowes employee about the compatible circuit breaker.
They recommended me the Homeline 50amp 2 poles standard but it seems doesn’t fit. (Or I did it wrong)
Can someone please take a look at the picture and let me know if I buy the correct breaker.




Yes I did a calculation. I’m installing a hardwired unit

according to the label on the currently installed main barker, you are using the right barker fro 50 Amp

90% of the time people who want 50A breakers for EVs are looking for the ole 14-50 RV park socket.  Those require GFCI protection in 90% of America and so you need a GFCI breaker for a socket.  DIYing this is fairly hazardous, we see LOTS of burn-ups either from hardwire connections not properly torqued, or cheap under-$30 range outlets used for the 14-50.  By the time you get the reliable $60 Hubbell/Bryant socket and the $120 GFCI breaker, it kinda takes the cost savings out of using the cheap mobile units. Wall units don't need sockets and thus not GFCIs.

Per the spec on information sheet on the box cover, type HOM should fit and is acceptable in this panel.  Typically there is a lip that the back edge of the breaker fits under, then the breaker itself angles into place pretty solidly.  If you include a picture of the breaker slots you're trying to fit it into, we might be able to see if there's anything wrong with where you're trying to insert it.

I’ve added the picture of the breaker slots. Please look at it again and let me know if the breaker fits into the panel. Thank you so much

Does it just not seem to seat all the way, and can you tell if there's anything blocking it fully seating?  It should fit just fine, but might take a bit of force to get it to seat, since I'm assuming the 50A breaker will be a pretty substantial connection to the bus bar prongs.

@Milwrdfan Breakers generally use the exact same bus clips for every rating, from 15A up to at least 100A (at some point, depending on brand, very large branch-circuit breakers take up four spaces instead of two). A two-pole breaker will take more effort to install compared to a one-pole, but it really doesn’t depend on the rating. Brand new parts may be stiffer too.
